# Continuing with the UI thread in a Task

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have many controls that create messages that need to be processed async.  I'd like to have a common function that updates the UI while the Task is running, but this is wrong(?) because when debugging the code in Visual Studio, it handles exceptions differently (See updated code at the bottom).

How do I re-write this code such that the common stuff is done correctly without duplicating the UI logic in every event handler?

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await myTaskAsync(button1);
}

private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await myTaskAsync(button2);
}

private async Task myTaskAsync(Button btn)
{
    string originalText = btn.Text;
    btn.Text = "Processing";
    btn.Enabled = false;

    await processAsync(btn.Tag);

    btn.Enabled = true;
    btn.Text = originalText;
}
```

Update:

Here's the updated (complete) example. Depending on where the call to the reset() function is, the exception generated in Visual Studio looks different. I don't understand this difference.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    NumericUpDown numeric = new NumericUpDown();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Button b1 = new Button();
        Controls.Add(b1);
        b1.Click += B1_Click;
        numeric.Maximum = 100;
    }

    private async void B1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await delay();
        // reset();
    }
    private void reset()
    {
        numeric.Value = 102;
    }

    private async Task delay()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: `await` automatically resumes on the UI thread.  "in a task" is meaningless.

Comment: Do you actually have any async / non-blocking work?

Comment: The call chain eventually awaits a TaskCompletionSource.Task which is completed by an ActionBlock

Comment: So when you run this code what problems are you having?

Comment: The UI code that was called after the button behaved different in Visual Studio. (it was generating an exception differently if it was placed inside the Task as opposed to putting the code in the event handlerr). This led me to assume the code is smells and I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @David As has been mentioned already, saying, "in a task" doesn't even make sense as a phrase.  All of the code you've shown here all runs in the UI thread.  If you're getting errors as a result of code not running in the UI thread when it needs to, then you'll need to provide an example that properly reproduces that.

Comment: @Servy Yes, sorry my phrasing is bad there. I understand that all of the code is running in the UI thread, but I do not understand why Visual Studio handles the exception differently in debug mode.  I have provided a complete example, if you want to run and test the 2 different methods of calling the reset() function you can see the differences.

Comment: @David Both of them are running the `reset` method in the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy Yes. But Visual Studio generates debug mode handles the exceptions differently, and I don't understand why.

Comment: How does it handle them differently?

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
private async void Buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
        await myTaskAsync(button);
}
```

Just change the event handler for all buttons to buttons_Click:

```
button1.Click += Buttons_Click;
button2.Click += Buttons_Click;
```